# Функция не принимает аргументом, переменные которые берут значения инпутов value из dom-a

Tags: javascript, функции, dom

Есть задача на дружественные числа. Если сумма делителей числа 220 равно сумме делителей 284, то тогда такие числа дружественные. Собственно я все прописал, не могу только запихнуть значения value в аргументы фунции isFriendly(arg1, arg2). Поможете?

```
    <label>Первое число: <input type="number" class="number1"></label>
    <label>Второе число: <input type="number" class="number2"></label>
    <button>Прверить</button>

    let num1 = document.querySelector('.number1');
    let num2 = document.querySelector('.number2');
    let btn = document.querySelector('button');

    btn.addEventListener('click', isFriendly);

    /* Пытаюсь что-то такое сделать, isFriendly(Number(num1.value), Number(num2.value)); 
    не работает. */

    /*
    number1 = 220; number2 = 284;
    220: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55, 110 = 284;
    284: 1, 2, 4, 71, 142 = 220;
    */

    function isFriendly(number1, number2) {
        if(getDivisorsSum(number1) === number2 && getDivisorsSum(number2) === number1) {
            return console.log('Дружественные');
        } else {
            return console.log('Не дружественные');
        }
    }

    function getDivisorsSum(num) {
        return getSum(getDivisors(num));
    }

    function getDivisors(num) {
        let arr = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < num; i++) {
            if(num % i === 0) {
                arr.push(i);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    function getSum(arr) {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: isFriendly(number1.value, number2.value) ?

Comment: querySelector дает ссылку на HTMLElement,  из HTMLElement нужно взять value

Comment: Можете еще раз просмотреть :) Только что редакцию сделал. В консоли выводит "Не дружественные, ввожу 220 и 284.

Comment: Комментарии про вызов функции.

Comment: либо так
let number1 = document.querySelector('.number1').value;

либо в isFriendly функции, выбераешь value подразумевая что туда входить htmlelement

Answer (score 0):

В обработчик надо передавать callback

```
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => isFriendly(Number(num1.value), Number(num2.value)));
```

Или можно определить числа сразу в функции isFriendly

```
function isFriendly() {
    const number1 = Number(num1.value);
    const number2 = Number(num2.value);
    if(getDivisorsSum(number1) === number2 && getDivisorsSum(number2) === number1) {
        return console.log('Дружественные');
    } else {
        return console.log('Не дружественные');
    }
}
```

Comment: В первом примере я ничего не понял, потому что до колбеков я еще не доходил. А во втором примере почему именно const использовали?А что если let использовать или var?

Comment: Const, потому что эти переменные в дальнейшем не меняются. Если использовать let или var в данном случае ничего не изменится.